# View/search iPhone text message history

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

How do I read and/or search the history of text messages from my iPhone? Some messages are SMS, others are iMessage, often interleaved within the same conversation. My understanding is that the phone keeps the entire history (which is why there is the "Load Earlier Messages" button, which is incredibly tedious to use, slows down with each additional click and offers no [obvious] way of searching).

Comment: Please edit this to reflect your situation. It's not useful without those details and attracting junk answers hence the moderation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 7, swipe down on the homescreen to bring up the search tool. You can search for SMS/iMessages and they will be brought up as you type. For iOS 6 and others, you can go one page to the left of the homescreen to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can search that way but when selecting the conversation you were looking for it takes you to the latest conversation , not the particular one you searched and selected.